# Cannot find mistake js syntax

Tags: javascript

Why do I get Unexpected end of input here:

```
row.
  append($("<a href='javascript:downloadFile('" + filename + "');'>" + filename + "</a>"));
```

`row` is defined, `filename` is normal string?

Comment: nothing wrong with that code as-is. you need to show more of the surrounding code. and are you getting the error at runtime, or at load/parse time?

Comment: Probably missing a parenthesis or bracket somewhere in the surrounding code

Comment: The single comma for your function parameters are closing the single comma used for the href. Use double quotes for the href and escape them.

Comment: One error i see is that you are missing " in href. href=" 'javascript.

Comment: @MarcB: The obvious error is missing escaping. The not-so-obvious error is quadruple use of the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem come from the four single-quotes `'` you have inside append so it will be considered the `href` attribute as :

> 'javascript:downloadFile('

Use double-quotes `"` intead of single ones and escape them, example :

```
$('body').append($("<a href=\"javascript:downloadFile('" + filename + "');\">" + filename + "</a>"));
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var filename = "file name test";

$('body').append($("<a href=\"javascript:downloadFile('" + filename + "');\">" + filename + "</a>"));

function downloadFile(file_name){
  alert(file_name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, the first one doesn't work. You cannot use the backslash to escape attribute delimiters, you have to use `&#39;` or `&apos;`

Comment: I meant the solution [you posted first](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38248565/1), then amended with a second solution and finally edited out. It's OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
row.append($("<a href='javascript:downloadFile(\"" + filename + "\");'>" + filename + "</a>"));
```

Your original code results in the following string:

```
<a href='javascript:downloadFile('file1234.txt');'>file1234.txt</a>;
```

As you see, the second ' ends the string. So you href attribute is in fact:

```
href='javascript:downloadFile('
```

that won't work.

Comment: That's still susceptible to XSS and HTML injection.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is from the use of the apostrophe as the delimiter for both HTML attribute and the JS string. A resulting source would look like

```html
<a href='javascript:downloadFile('123.example');'>123.example</a>
<!--    ^                        ^           ^  ^ -->
```

Instead of templating HTML without any escaping, use the DOM! jQuery is quite convenient to use here. For the JS string, use `JSON.stringify` to escape it:

```
row.append($("<a />", {
    href: 'javascript:downloadFile(' + JSON.stringify(filename) + ');',
    text: filename
}));
```

But even better, don't use `javascript:` URIs!!! Just add an event handler:

```
row.append($("<a />", {text: filename}).click(function(e) {
    downloadFile(filename);
});
```